# OrderBy clause breaking in Cassandra and Java Spring Pagination

Tags: java, spring-boot, cassandra, jhipster

This code is correct in terms of paging logic, but it's throwing an error: `ORDER BY is only supported when the partition key is restricted by an EQ or an IN.`

```
    @GetMapping("/users")
    public ResponseEntity<List<User>> getAllUsers(Pageable pageable) {
        log.debug("REST request to get a page of Users");

        // Creates a Page by slicing the total list of pages via the pagination indices
        Slice<User> users = usersRepository.findAll(pageable);
        Page<User> page = new PageImpl<>(users.toList(), pageable, pageable.getPageSize());

        HttpHeaders headers = PaginationUtil.generatePaginationHttpHeaders(ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentRequest(), page);
        return ResponseEntity.ok().headers(headers).body(page.getContent());
    }
```

Now I understand *why* it's failing and I understand the error. The method `usersRepository.findAll(pageable);` is forcing Cassandra to make this request `SELECT * users from users_table ORDER BY id ASC`

The ordering method is not allowed unless we specify a partition, but I don't know how to do that in this interface. How can I update the `usersRepository.findAll(pageable);` request so that the IN or EQ condition is satisfied?

This code was partially auto-generated by JHipster. Originally it wasn't even compiling, but now we're here.

Comment: JHipster's Pagination implementation does not work with Cassandra.  You can customize a query in UserRepository to add more params, possibly to enable what you are trying.  See https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-sample-app-cassandra/blob/4f1fc6144737c91d8378f8ae0502673443c4db47/src/main/java/io/github/jhipster/sample/repository/UserRepository.java#L69

Comment: @JonRuddell lame. I'm going to make my own Queries I guess in SQL. Seems super outdated to have to build my own SQL queries with all the other junk going on in the ORM, but I don't really know what else to do. Thank you.